# Understand how to also get an access token for down stream api access for web app with OneLogin

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, onelogin, blazor-webassembly

I've been at this for days and the documentation just isn't clear to me, maybe I'm just not reading it correctly.

I have a blazor WASM app (https://localhost:5001) that pulls data from an api. The api needs to be authenticated so I want to just pass the access token inside the header.

Inside the OneLogin admin dashboard I've created an OIDC app called "testApp", the Token Endpoint is None (PKCE).

Setting up oidcauthentication on blazor was super simple. I originall just used the

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
        {
           builder.Configuration.Bind("OneLogin", options.ProviderOptions);

         })
```

However I quickly realized I had no way to add an audience. So I followed this guide ..

[auth0 oidc for blazor](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-blazor-webassembly-apps/#Calling-the-Protected-API)
and this github for the actual code I modified to create a custom provideroptions that has an audience string
[github repo](https://github.com/StefH/Blazor.WebAssembly.Authentication.Auth0)

And I also had no issues setting it up. However, where I get stuck is how seemingly complicated OneLogin's side of the setup is.

Reading their docs [onelogin api auth docs](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/api-authorization/overview), there are no modern examples of setting it up past the postman import. Downloading the import file offers a fairly organized set of apis however I can't figure out what needs to go where.

First I created an Api Auth Server

```
 {
    "description": "API",
    "configuration": {
        "access_token_expiration_minutes": 20,
        "refresh_token_expiration_minutes": 20,
        "resource_identifier": "https://localhost:5005",
        "audiences": [
            "https://localhost:5005/worker",
            "https://localhost:5005/user"
        ]
    },
    "name": "API"
}
```

then I created a scope

```
{ "value": "custom:scope",
"description": "A custom scope" }
```

then I added api auth server client. I went to the admin panel and grabbed the app id from the url. https://{domain}.onelogin.com/apps/{appId}/edit/#configuration

and added an api auth server

which gave me this back from the postman api

```
[
{
    "name": "TestApp",
    "app_id": 1111111,
    "scopes": [
        {
            "id": 172,
            "description": "A custom scope",
            "value": "custom:scope"
        }
    ],
    "api_auth_id": 1246001
}]
```

So from this point it looks like I have everything I need? Except I still can't get it to create an access token. I go back to my application and use the modified service and add my audience to my appsettings.json

```
"OneLogin": {
"Authority": "https://{domain}.onelogin.com/oidc/2/",
"ClientId": "{clientId from onelogin}",
"ResponseType": "code",
"DefaultScopes": "openid profile groups",
"Audience": "https://localhost:5005"
```

Except it still doesn't add the extra audience to the access token causing my api calls to fail when I add the access token inside the header. If anyone can figure out where I've gone wrong I'd be incredibly grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

woot. Figured it out myself. I had everything right but I had the audience wrong. In their docs they discuss having multiple audiences like example.com/blah and example.com/bleh but having the audience as just example.com and then having different scopes PER web service actually is working fine.

So when I create example2.com and add it to the audience both my api's will be able to be accessed.